# Как вернуть значение в функции axios

Tags: javascript, axios

Имеется функция с `axios` запросом и при его вызове, он возвращает `Promise`. А мне нужно `true/false`

```
async checkPermission ({}, rolename) {
    try {
        const response = await $http.get('/check/role?rolename='+rolename)
        if(response.data.role_required) {
            return true
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err)
    }
 }
```

При попытке вызвать его `console.log(this.checkPermission('Администратор'))`

Я получаю

[image: Результат вызова функции]

Comment: console.log(await this.checkPermission('Администратор'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
async checkPermission ({}, rolename) {
    try {
        const response = await $http.get('/check/role?rolename='+rolename)
        if(response.data.role_required) {
            return true
        }
        else{
            return false
        }
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err)
    }
}

async () => {
    result = await checkPermission({}, 'Администратор')
    console.log(result)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Помогло